# Блок поиска, содержащий результаты поиска

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы форма с результатами поиска показывалась под инпутом поиска, как в твиттере. (Посмотрел исходный код - там все занесено в один div). Сам вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы блок был под инпутом, а инпут в `<li>`.(После само меню представляет собой li список, при уменьшении окна браузера сжимается). Цель - сделать так, чтобы был див под инпутом, который в теге `<li>` меню (после div должен быть, не в меню и ниже его). Заранее спасибо! Вот пример, как должно выглядеть картинкой.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду то, что при наборе фразы в поле поиска автоматически появляются возможные результаты, то это ни что иное, как [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). К примеру, на [этой демонстрационной странице](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache), начните вводить названия птиц (на англ.) - crow (ворона) или eagle (орёл) - и увидите результат работы.

Comment: В результаты поиска можно бедут я как понимаю и картинку с фото пользователя ?

Comment: @OverLoader, Любую информацию: текст, ссылки, графику etc.

Comment: А что в поиске который находиться в Твиттере используется ?

Comment: @OverLoader, учитывая, что они используют jQuery, можно предположить, что Autocomplete так же пользуются. Хотя, организовать этот процесс зная ajax - не так уж сложно и самому.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Разобрался!

Answer (score 2):

Всплывающий блок должен быть абсолютно позиционирован относительно пункта меню, при наведении на который, всплывает само меню. Следовательно, всплывающий блок в стилях должен иметь `position:absolute` и "сдвиг" вниз на высоту пункта меню, а для того, что-бы позиционирование происходило относительно родительского блока, у пункта меню должен быть `position:relative`.

`CSS`:

```
.menu,.menu li,.under-menu li{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
}
.menu li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.under-menu li{
    float:none;
}
.under-menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}
.menu li:hover .under-menu{
    display:block;
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        Пункт #1
    </li>
    <li>
        Пункт #2
        <ul class="under-menu">
            <li>Подпункт 1</li>
            <li>Подпункт 2</li>
            <li>Подпункт 3</li>
            <li>Подпункт 4</li>
            <li>Подпункт 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Наглядный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/acGW6/embedded/result/).